# How to change toolbar background color in jodit-react

Tags: css, reactjs, wysiwyg, text-editor, jodit

I'm using jodit-react editor. Honestly the documentation is confusing a bit. This is my current config to add custom style to the WSYIWYG editor but I'm not able to change the background-color and the text-color for the toolbar.

```
const config = {
        readonly: false, // all options from https://xdsoft.net/jodit/doc/
        height: '450px',
        width: '100%',
        enableDragAndDropFileToEditor: true,
        buttons: [
            'source',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'underline',
            '|',
            'ul',
            'ol',
            '|',
            'font',
            'fontsize',
            'brush',
            'paragraph',
            '|',
            'image',
            'table',
            'link',
            '|',
            'left',
            'center',
            'right',
            'justify',
            '|',
            'undo',
            'redo',
            '|',
            'hr',
            'eraser',
            'fullsize',
        ],
        uploader: { insertImageAsBase64URI: true },
        removeButtons: ['brush', 'file'],
        showXPathInStatusbar: false,
        showCharsCounter: false,
        showWordsCounter: false,
        toolbarAdaptive: true,
        toolbarSticky: true,
        style: {
            background: '#27272E',
            color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
        },
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe, you can check this

*toolbar*: https://xdsoft.net/jodit/doc/options/toolbar/

**Type:** [boolean | string | HTMLElement].

Comment: Thank you this helps, but the toolbar doesn't the change the color in an expected manner, it only has two values for dark and light theme. I've modified the above with css.